# Ansible vars_prompt & with_items and split

Tags: ansible

To be more clear from my previous Playbook. I am trying to pass 2 switch IP's to get the available ports on both the switches. When I am trying to pass one switch IP, It is executing fine. When i am trying to pass 2 IP's separating by split "SPACE" it is only executing on First switch IP.But not taking the second IP. Please see execution output and respective playbook
Ansible version : 2.6.1

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt:
  - name: ip_addr
    prompt: Please enter the switch name
    private: no
  vars_files:
    - ../vars/password.yml
  tasks:
  - add_host:
      name : "{{ item }}"
      groups: dynamically_created_hosts
    with_items: "{{ip_addr.split(' ')}}"
  - name: display all available ports
    display_available_ports:
        switch_ip: "{{ip_addr}}"
        user: "{{user}}"
        password: "{{password}}"
        vfid: -1
    register: result
  - debug: var=result


[root@san1 working]# ansible-playbook port_available_test.yml
Please enter the switch name: 17.16.15.16
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
TASK [add_host] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=17.16.15.16)
TASK [display all available ports] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "available_ports": [
            {
                "name": "0/1",
                "port-type": "F_PORT"
            },
            {
                "name": "0/2",
                "port-type": "F_PORT"
            }
        ],
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0



[root@san1 working]# ansible-playbook port_available_test.yml
Please enter the switch name: 17.16.15.16 17.16.15.17
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
TASK [add_host] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=17.16.15.16)
changed: [localhost] => (item=17.16.15.17)
TASK [display all available ports] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "available_ports": [
            {
                "name": "0/1",
                "port-type": "F_PORT"
            },
            {
                "name": "0/2",
                "port-type": "F_PORT"
            }
        ],
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Hi Srini A, welcome to SO! You will need to post any **error** you are receiving when you say "not performing," because it works fine for me. You should definitely include sample input of the `ip_addr` that works, followed by sample input of `ip_addr` that doesn't work. Good luck!

Comment: I have added my playbook and execution output. Please advice me on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     switch_ip: "{{ip_addr}}"
> ```

That value is the one from the prompt, and thus contains the space delimited version you typed in.

I think what you want is to move the `with_items:` to that actual task, since `add_host:` doesn't change the execution plan for `hosts: localhost`:

```
- name: display all available ports
  display_available_ports:
      switch_ip: "{{item}}"
      # etc
  with_items: "{{ip_addr.split(' ')}}"
```